# How to put these metrics into a formula to describe their dependency on each other?

Tags: statistics, principal-component-analysis

I'm not a mathematician - far from that, but in a current task I think about, I come to idea, that the solution can be found only on mathematics way.

I have five metrics, and I want to get a formula, which describes, how these metrics are relying to each other.

There are two sets of metrics.

**The first metrics set** describes keyword. It contains

- keyword,
- its monthly search volume (how many users search it on Google),
- competition (which is from 0 to 1 and describes whether there are many websites, who want trigger ads with this keyword) and
- suggested bid (which displays, divided by a million, the CPC, cost-per-click - the click price, which is paid by advertiser to Google, if somebody clicks on te ad triggered by this keyword).

Here is the first metrics set:

```
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| Keyword   | Monthly Search Volume | Competition | Suggested Bid |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| keyword 1 | 110000                | 0.840621281 | 6826196       |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| keyword 2 | 12100                 | 0.773800314 | 6156644       |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| keyword 3 | 5400                  | 0.94185553  | 8001839       |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| keyword 4 | 1900                  | 0.790711928 | 3700900       |
+-----------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

**The second metrics set** describes a pair `keyword-domain` and contains

- keyword,
- domain,
- ranking place (where Google shows the domain's url for this keyword).

To the ranking place from this metrics set belongs additional metric - *CTR*.

*CTR* is click-through-rate, which is probability in per cent of the fact user clicks on the url in search results. Click-through-rate applies like a bonus only to the first 20 ranking places.

Here are keywords ranking places and urls.

```
+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| Keyword   | Ranking Place | URL                    |
+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| keyword 1 | 1             | https://example.com/p1 |
+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| keyword 2 | 8             | https://example.com/p2 |
+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| keyword 3 | 19            | https://example.com/p3 |
+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
| keyword 4 | 29            | https://example.com/p4 |
+-----------+---------------+------------------------+
```

And here are CTRs for all 20 ranking places.

```
+---------------+--------------------+
| Ranking Place | Click Through rate |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 1             | 45.99              |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 2             | 21.12              |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 3             | 13.51              |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 4             | 8.36               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 5             | 5.71               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 6             | 3.96               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 7             | 2.96               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 8             | 2.10               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 9             | 1.66               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 10            | 1.29               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 11            | 1.17               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 12            | 1.14               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 13            | 1.41               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 14            | 1.46               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 15            | 1.54               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 16            | 1.56               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 17            | 1.33               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 18            | 1.15               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 19            | 0.90               |
+---------------+--------------------+
| 20            | 1.02               |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

What I want: I want to calculate a parameter as reliance of all metrics on each other. I would name it `visibility of certain keyword`.

**Example**: the visibility of certain keyword would be like

[image]

I'm very unsure in my math and would be happy about any advice!